# Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Dymola

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, dymola

I would like to use Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0's built in C compiler for simulation in 32-bit Dymola Demo Version 2017. I have opted to include C++ compiler during MVS installation and the files exist in the proper locations. When passing Dymola the location to the compiler, I receive the error:

```
Compiling and linking the model (Visual C++). 
Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin\vcvars32"
  or
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin\vcvars32" store
"Testing 32-bit compilation" 
The command "cl" is either misspelled or could not be found.
```

Below attached are my settings.
[image: Simulation Setup]

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft have changed some scripts or directory structure.
Visual Studio 2015 (aka 14.0) is supported out of the box by Dymola 2017 FD01 or newer,
so the easiest solution would probably be to switch to the very latest Dymola version:
https://www.3ds.com/products-services/catia/products/dymola/latest-release/

Also, when installing newer versions of Visual Studio, you should make sure to install the C++ components!!
If you forgot to install those, you can still install them later by following these steps:

- open Visual Studio
- click File, New, Project, then Templates, Visual C++
- if the C++ parts are not installed, you will have the option to install them here
- after that, you should be able to run the compiler test as shown in the screenshot below

[image]